# On Prem Application migration to the AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-applications, cloud, data-migration, hybrid-cloud

We are migrating some of our J2EE based application from on-prem to the AWS cloud. I am trying to find some good document on what steps to be considered for the App migration. Since we already have an AWS account, and some of the applications have been migrated earlier, I don't have to worry about those aspects.. However I am thinking more towards
- Which App-server to use?
- Do i need to migrate DB as well..or just the App?
- Any licensing requirements for app.. we use mostly Open source.. So that should be fine..
- Operational monitoring after migrating to cloud..

Came across some of these articles.

- https://serverguy.com/cloud/aws-migration/
- Migration Scenario: Migrating Web Applications to the AWS Cloud : https://d36cz9buwru1tt.cloudfront.net/CloudMigration-scenario-wep-app.pdf

I would like to know If you have worked on this kind of work.. and If you point me to some helpful document/links.. or your pwn experience?

Answer (score 1):

So theres 2 good resources I'd recommend for migration:

- [AWS Whitepaper for migration](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/Migration/aws-migration-whitepaper.pdf)
- [AWS Well-Architected Framework](https://aws.amazon.com/architecture/well-architected/).

The key is planning, but not being afraid to experiment. This is cloud so don't be afraid of setting an instance size in stone, you can easily change it.